# I have added a new font into my pc and i want to use that font in my java applet, how can i do that?

Tags: java, fonts, applet

```
try {
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,new File("‪C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\fonts\\digital-7.ttf") );
} catch (FontFormatException | IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Calculator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}

font = font.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN,30);
GraphicsEnvironment ge =
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
ge.registerFont(font);
```

This method is not working.

Comment: How is it not working? What is the error?

Comment: I don't know by using this method my font of textfield does't change .

Comment: i'm getting this error

Comment: SEVERE: null
java.io.IOException: Can't read ?C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\fonts\digital-7.ttf
 at java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1054)
 at New.Calculator.init(Calculator.java:46)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

java.lang.NullPointerException
 at New.Calculator.init(Calculator.java:50)
 at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:434)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: 1) Why code an applet?  If it is due to the teacher specifying it, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). 3) All applet resources for applets, must be **loaded by URL** from the server. ..

Comment: .. When deployed, they cannot load fonts installd on your (or the user's) PC.